# How to use joins in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, join, lumen

I have this query:

```
SELECT fname, gender FROM users, speciality WHERE users.id = userSpeciality.user_id AND type = 2
```

I want the same query in Lumen. I have tried something like this but it doesnt work:

```
$users   = Speciality::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'speciality.user_id')
           ->where('type' => 2)
           ->select('fname', 'gender')
           ->get();
```

Table : `speciality` is the main table here. Which contains user ids.

Comment: Do you have an error? Or just not the expected result?

Comment: It gives me a syntax error : syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Oh right, it's ->where('type',2)

Answer (score 1):

If `Speciality` is not an `Eloquent` model then just do:

```
DB::table('speciality')->join(....)->get();
```

Otherwise patricus has posted the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132026/220086).

Comment: You do not need the call to `query()`. When you call a method on an Eloquent model that does not exist, it automatically creates a new query builder for that model and redirects the function to that query builder. Therefore, `Specialty::join(...)->get();` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where()` argument is not formatted properly. It should be `where('type', '=', 2)`.

```
$users = Speciality::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'speciality.user_id')
    ->where('type', '=', 2)
    ->select('fname', 'gender')
    ->get();
```

Additionally, since it is User information you're after, if you're using Eloquent and your relationships are setup correctly, you could do the following:

```
User::whereHas('specialty', function($query) {
    $query->where('type', '=', 2);
});
```

Comment: Is the rest of the query fine? I mean logic wise?

Comment: I am confused how it will detect what users is ?

Comment: @NewCo As far as translating the exact query you gave into using the Fluent syntax, the code is fine. As far as whether or not the logic is correct, that all depends on what your intended logic is. Right now, your query will get a list of fname, gender that has a related specialty with the type of 2.

Comment: Comment erroneously posted on another question from @NewCo: "What do you prefer here? I want to fetch those users whose user_id exists in speciality table. What can be the best approach to acheive? I am using : use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;".

Comment: Yes I mistakenly posted my comment on my another question. Sorry for that

Comment: @NewCo Since you're using Eloquent, I would suggest using the second version. Make sure the relationships are setup correctly and then you can write the code exactly as intended: get the users that have a specialty where the type is 2.